# Cannot resolve symbol FirebaseRecyclerOptions

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am creating app for my semester project where I use firebase as backend and trying to fetch data from the firebase realtime database but the issue i am facing is that i am using recycle view inside fragment and and when I pasted code from firebase documents its not importing the relative imports and keep giving `cannot resolve error`.

Here is my fragment class code:

```
public class homeFragrment extends Fragment {

  View view;
  RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_fragrment, container, false);
        ImageSlider imageSlider=view.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);
        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        ArrayList<SlideModel> slideModels=new ArrayList<>();
        slideModels.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.f, ScaleTypes.FIT));
        slideModels.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.s, ScaleTypes.FIT));
        slideModels.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.t, ScaleTypes.FIT));
        slideModels.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.fo, ScaleTypes.FIT));
        slideModels.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.fi, ScaleTypes.FIT));
        imageSlider.setImageList(slideModels,ScaleTypes.FIT);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rooms"), model.class)
                        .build();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle file looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.hostelmanagement'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hostelmanagement"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:x.x.x'
    implementation 'com.github.denzcoskun:ImageSlideshow:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'

}
```

I also watched a tutorial those guys are also getting auto import but for me it hot happening how to overcome this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency and check

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.2'